# Фильтрация файлов при выполнении scp

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

Хочу скопировать с удаленного компьютера все файлы - с каким-нибудь фильтром. Например, по названию: содержащие слово `file` как-то так:

```
$ scp user@192.168.1.10:/home/user/$(ls | grep file)
```

Не работает. Как можно это сделать - без копирования всего содержимого папки и фильтрации на локальном компьютере?

Comment: Если файлов не много, можно попробовать таким образом:
scp user@remote.host:~/\{file1,file2,file3\} .

Comment: К сожалению, имена файлов и их количество заранее неизвестны) Нужен именно фильтр)

Answer (score 3):

вложенная оболочка (определяемая конструкцией `$()`) будет запущена на локальной машине. поэтому результаты выполнения команды *ls* в данном случае вряд ли могут быть полезны.

копировать в текущий каталог файлы, содержажие слово *file*, можно, например, так:

```
$ scp user@192.168.1.10:/home/user/*file* .
```

искомое слово можно поместить в переменную:

```
$ v=file scp user@192.168.1.10:/home/user/*$v* .
```

более того, в ту же переменную можно поместить и поисковые квантификаторы:

```
$ v='*file*' scp user@192.168.1.10:/home/user/$v .
```